# Hello World in Apache

Tags: apache

I can't believe how many issues I've been having getting apache up and running. It's clearly not a run out-of-the-box type thing.

I'm running a web server on CentOS with `httpd` installed via `yum`.

I created a very basic hello world `index.html` here (`cgi-bin` and `html` was created by the install):

```
/var/www/
├── cgi-bin
└── html
    └── index.html
```

The `httpd` configuration directory is structured like so:

```
/etc/httpd
├── conf
│   ├── httpd.conf
│   └── magic
├── conf.d
│   ├── autoindex.conf
│   ├── README
│   ├── userdir.conf
│   └── welcome.conf
├── conf.modules.d
│   ├── 00-base.conf
│   ├── 00-dav.conf
│   ├── 00-lua.conf
│   ├── 00-mpm.conf
│   ├── 00-proxy.conf
│   ├── 00-systemd.conf
│   └── 01-cgi.conf
├── logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
├── modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
├── run -> /run/httpd
├── sites-available
│   └── http.conf
└── sites-enabled
    └── http.conf -> /etc/httpd/sites-available/http.conf
```

None of these files were created by me, but I did setup the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories, as these make more sense and I have seen this done before.

To get these directories work, I added:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

to the end of `httpd.conf`.

The `http.conf` file I wrote looks simply like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.name.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Running `httpd -t` reports `Syntax OK` and `httpd -S` prints the following:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   domain.name.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/http.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48 not_used
Group: name="apache" id=48 not_used
```

So everything looks pretty normal. Obviously, running `sudo service httpd restart` restarts without errors and the `httpd` logs look okay.

Checking `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log` doesn't also display anything exciting.

But, when I go to the server by IP or name (using `ping`, I determined that DNS is, in fact, correctly translating the name to the IP), I get a connection refused error.

I'm totally at a loss at what's going on and I'm at the end of my debugging rope. Any ideas?

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: can you access via localhost from the server? If you can then there is some firewall/ip rejection setting.

Comment: DANG! Should have thought of this sooner. `curl -I 'localhost'` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora (and I believe CentOS) have a pretty restrictive firewall by default, you need to use something like this to open port 80:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http
```

Pass --permanent once you're sure it's working. More details here: http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

Fedora also has some SELinux settings that by default restrict web servers from actually accessing files even though they look readable. You can use `getsebool/setsebool` to investigate this http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=240075

Comment: Also, I created an Apache config from scratch recently and it was always exiting without doing anything. It took me forever to realize I needed a `<Directory>` along with my `<VirtualHost>`.

Comment: Yep, I should have really considered this sooner, but this firewall rule fixed it. Thank you so much!